# oracle query with multiple subqueries

Tags: oracle

tryng to select table rows and then use subqueries to generate single row list (item1,item2,item3)

anyway sql:

```
select 
  username,
  concat(firstname || ' ', lastname) as name,
  email,
  phone,
  (
  select 
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(res, ', '), ', ')
  from (
    select 
      count(*) over() as cnt, 
      row_number() over(order by ofield) as rnum, 
      (select name from rooms where code=roomcode) as res 
    from adminrooms
    where roomcode=admins.code) /*admins.code - come from main query but it gives error: invalid identifier*/
  where cnt=rnum start with rnum=1 connect by prior rnum=(rnum-1)
  ) as groups
from admins
where frozen=0 and (type <> 'root' or type is null)
```

problem seems to be the main query field 'code' from table 'admins' don't work inside list generation query

Comment: You need to give more detail of the source tables (and data) and what you are expecting the results to look like.  I'd also be specific about the Oracle version.  Later versions implement a "PIVOT" clause to convert "rows" into "columns".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your db diagram, the best way to do it is to use a custom [string aggregation](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php) function and then just do a group by.  This is similar to mysql group_concat.

If you make a function called string_agg() using the above link, you can use it as below in your code:

```
select a.username, string_agg(c.name) from admins a, adminrooms b, groups c
where a.code=b.admincode
and b.groupcode=c.code
group by a.username
```

Here is the string_agg function create script.  Just run this as a script and you will have the function above (taken from the link shown above):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_agg AS OBJECT
(
  g_string  VARCHAR2(32767),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
     RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER
);
/
SHOW ERRORS


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_string_agg IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    sctx := t_string_agg(NULL);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := self.g_string || ',' || value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := RTRIM(LTRIM(SELF.g_string, ','), ',');
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := SELF.g_string || ',' || ctx2.g_string;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_agg (p_input VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_string_agg;
/
SHOW ERRORS
```

Comment: it work fine but the db where im going to use it doesn't have permissions for functions etc

so only option is table joining :(

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your findings with a simple example. Consider:

```
SQL> SELECT (SELECT d1.dummy FROM dual d2) d2
  2    FROM dual D1;

D2
--
X
```

This works because the subquery "d2" can see the rows of the main query "d1" but if we add a level I get the same error as you:

```
SQL> SELECT (SELECT NULL FROM (SELECT d1.dummy FROM dual d3))
  2  FROM dual D1;

SELECT (SELECT NULL FROM (SELECT d1.dummy FROM dual d3))
FROM dual D1                     ~

ORA-00904: "D1"."DUMMY": invalid identifier
```

Here the subquery "D3" can not see the values of the row from "D1".

You will have to modify your query:
 * join `admin` with `adminrooms` and then use the `sys_connect_by_path` or
 * write a function that will take a code as parameter and will output the result of your select.

Provide us with CREATE TABLE and sample data if you want an example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there is no column "code" in the "admins" table... it's just a little mistake. If there was, you wouldn't want to join with the roomcode of adminrooms, rather something like "admincode=admins.code".

Comment: checked tables and verified the columns and there idd was a typo
but now: where admincode=admins.code
gives "admins"."code": invalid identifier


both queries work separately but not together :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite you subquery

```
   (
    select 
      count(*) over() as cnt, 
      row_number() over(order by ofield) as rnum, 
      (select name from rooms where code=roomcode) as res 
    from adminrooms
    where roomcode=admins.code)
```

as table in main query like

```
 ... from admins, 
       (
        select 
          roomcode,
          count(*) over() as cnt, 
          row_number() over(order by ofield) as rnum, 
          (select name from rooms where code=roomcode) as res 
        from adminrooms) t
 where t.roomcode = admins.code...
```

And use `wmsys.WM_CONCAT()` instead of `sys_connect_by_path()`

Comment: Note that wmsys.wm_concat() is an undocumented function. You'll want to think twice before using that in a production environment.